# Get random values from a row while two values that exist are not selected together

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do something I think rather tricky and can't wrap my head around it. Kinda driving me nuts. Seems like it should be easier than it is.

So I have two tables. I display two items together randomly. When you pick an item, it gets entered into the DB as a vote for that item with the `item ID` stored in `win_id` column and the other item goes into the `lst_id` column. Then it displays two more random items and so on and so on. Now my problem is once they choose an item, I never want those two pair to be shown again to that user. The items can be shown with other items that haven't been voted on against however. Hope this is making since. 
This is the query I'm trying unsuccessfully.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT be.media_id FROM battle_entries as be 
WHERE be.btype=1 AND be.mature=1 AND be.mem_id!=1 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM battle_votes as bv 
WHERE bv.win_id = be.media_id AND bv.mem_id=1 AND bv.lst_id=be.media_id)) s ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2";
```

The `win_id` and the `lst_id` are the pair that has been chosen by the user. I never want those two be shown together to the same user again, if they exist in the battle_votes table by that user, but still being randomly selected with other items that haven't been shown together.

Here are the tables

battle_entries

```
----------------------------------------------------
| btl_id | mem_id | posted | media_id | active |
----------------------------------------------------
```

battle_votes

```
----------------------------------------------------
| btl_id | mem_id | win_id | lst_id | posted |
----------------------------------------------------
```

If there is a better way to do it with a different schema, I'm open to that too if this is not possible.

**Edit:**
Best I can explain it again.

My query selects 2 random items that the user has not voted on. Once the user chooses one, a new row is created in the battle_votes table. The chosen `item ID` is entered into the `win_id` column and the not chosen goes into the `lst_id` column. `This is a single row.` Now the next time it does a random select to show two more items, I don't want those 2 to be shown again as a `pair`, but each one can be shown with another item that hasn't entered into the battle_votes table as a `pair`. I know it might be confusing.

Basically I don't want the same pair to ever show again together, if they have chosen either item.

Comment: Are you re-inventing Facebook from scratch? ;) (might not make sense to those who haven't seen The Social Network or read much about the history of fb)

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your database and also on the options available (I've never worked with Postgre) one of the suggestions might be to generate a random pair the way you're doing it (without all the conditions, just order all `media_id`'s randomly and take the top 2), save them into two variables and then check if this pair is already in the `battle_votes` table (in either order); if yes throw it away and generate a new pair. 
This is already some SQL programming however - not sure if you have the option of writing and running stored procedures.

Comment: @Helena lol No not trying to reinvent but I know what you're talking about. I thought about having two queries or using a loop do until loop but I thought it might be expensive. I might have to go that route. I seems I've stumped some of the SQL pro's around or either they don't want to answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to pivot rows into columns, choose one pair you need and then unpivot it back:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        be.media_id
    from battle_entries as be
    where be.btype = 1 and be.mature = 1 and be.mem_id != 1 
), cte2 as (
    select
        be1.media_id as media_id1,
        be2.media_id as media_id2
    from cte1 as be1
        inner join cte1 as be2 on be2.media_id <> be1.media_id
), cte3 as (
    select c.media_id1, c.media_id2
    from cte2 as c
    where
        not exists
        (
            select *
            from battle_votes as bv 
            where
                bv.mem_id = 1 and
                (
                    bv.win_id = c.media_id1 and bv.lst_id = c.media_id2 or
                    bv.win_id = c.media_id2 and bv.lst_id = c.media_id1
                )
        )
    order by random()
    limit 1
)
select media_id1 as media_id from cte3
union all
select media_id2 as media_id from cte3
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c02be/11)

Comment: Interesting. is that all one query that is ran including the Selects at the bottom?

Comment: yep, wait a sec, have to test it in sqlfiddle

Comment: Ok no problem, also skip unpivot by modifying how?

Comment: @Pjack so if pair is already in votes (win_id = 1, lst_id = 2) you don't want to see it in other way (win_id =2, lst_id = 1) too?

Comment: That's correct I don't want the select to show it the other way either for that `user` that's why I also add the `mem_id=x`. Once it's in the votes, regardless of order 1,2 or 2,1, it is not shown again as pair. I think you understand it now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I think you might have misunderstood part of it. I need to select 2 random `media_id` entries from `battle_entries` as long as it's not any pair in the battle_votes table. I think you got that. But the sqlfiddle is giving me win_id, I need the select to be media_id. Also when I tested it in my app, it yields no results at all. :/

Comment: Ok I can use win_id for the result and just change the part in the app because the fiddle seems to work but with my actual app it gives no results. Could it be the additional columns in the where clause since the fiddle is just basic?

Comment: I'm an idiot. :) I forgot to update part of your example in my app. It works fine. Thank you.

Comment: I've added an alias to the answer, so you could use media_id

Comment: One quick question, is there a way to not have an empty array unless all possible combinations are used? As the quantity of available random pairs diminish, it sometimes shows an empty array even though there are still values it can randomly show. Because if I refresh again, it gives me another pair.

Answer (score 0):

You either want separate tables for battles and victories, or just extra columns in the battle table. Add the two IDs, but make sure the smaller ID is always the first one.

```
(btl_id, mem_id, id1, id2, win_id, lst_id, ...)
```

Then you just throw a unique constraint/index over `(mem_id,id1,id2)`. If you're not using a particularly rubbish ORM then you can drop `btl_id` too - it's redundant.

Comment: Thanks perhaps if I need to change the schema later on because I don't know how the speed will be with large data, I might try this approach but the tables are not infinite and will be purged regularly so I think @Roman Pekar's answer will work.